# Mongodb write issues

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to mongodb and I am getting write issues with it. Actually I can have around 2000 users connecting to the server and each writing their stuffs in mongodb. I tried sleep for around 20 secs before and after each write. But even that is not working as I can have many threads doing same thing at same instance. That is not controllable. Can making an another Mongo instance(i.e. each user will make a new connection to the same host on same database) for each user work? Or may be anything else that can solve this issue? Plz help..

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: It is not writing into the database and before that only it reads. This is actually because write into mongoDB is too slow. And I have concurrency in my program.

Comment: Please be (a lot more) precise about the problem you're having, the solution you tried and what MongoDB and/or the driver are reporting when something goes wrong. If it fails silently post (a simplified reproduction version of) your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting a specific error when trying to write?  Sleeping for a number of seconds would only be deferring the same problem (and probably causing more issues by artificially adding delay to your application).  Also, are you just doing inserts .. or updates/upserts?  A brief bit of example code for the problematic write would be helpful.

Suggested approaches to investigate will vary depending on where your resource bottleneck is: http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/9/13/must-see-5-steps-to-scaling-mongodb-or-any-db-in-8-minutes.html

Comment: No. It just gives me null pointer exception when I am reading it from my code in java. And when I see through the command line whether that collection is present or anything is there in that collection which I am trying to read then it is just empty or may be that collection has not been written also till now and before that only I am reading.

Comment: Suggest reviewing the information on [concurrency with MongoDB Java driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Driver+Concurrency).

In particular, try the SAFE commit to make sure your data is being saved, e.g `coll.insert(..., WriteConcern.SAFE);`

A related SO question on [catching exceptions on inserts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926352/mongodb-java-driver-catch-exception-when-insert-fails) that may help.